# launch file find with current pkg name

Tags: ros, roslaunch, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

Is there a way to resolve the current pkg folder name related to a launch file?
My launch files uses the

> $(find current_pkg)/my_file.xy

substitution to find and resolve a file in my current package.
Every time I am renaming my pkg or if have to check all the finds.
Is there a more common way such as

> $(CURRENT_PKG)/my_file.xy

Greetings
Markus

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242047/launch-file-find-with-current-pkg-name/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2016-08-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2020-11-10**:
Is there anything new on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can set a system-wide environment variable for CURRENT_PKG (might need to put it in ~/.bashrc file), you can swap the $(find current_pkg) part with $(env CURRENT_PKG).

---

Originally posted by [ElizabethA](https://answers.ros.org/users/26773/elizabetha/) with karma: 120 on 2016-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2016-11-13**:
nice idea, but i have multiple such packages.

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2020-11-10**:
Is there anything new on this?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-11-10**:
@Markus Bader: posting comments on an answered question from 2016 is not the most visible way to ask for updates.

I happened to notice as I'm *watching* this question, but without that, your comment would be almost invisible.